# Where to store terms and conditions when generating custom Quote PDF?

Tags: visualforce, custom-field, pdf, quote

I am designing custom Quote PDF for our company and the last section on the PDF is for showing the terms and conditions.

On which object should I store the terms and conditions? I was thinking of creating a custom field on the Organization object but I do not see a way to create custom field on the organization object.

If anybody faced the same situation, Please help me on this:

1. Admin should be able to modify the terms and conditions from UI
   without touching the code.
2. I think it should be Rich Text Area
   field.

Any other best approach to solve this problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In similar situation I created a single record custom object ... I offered the client to have few place holders on the quote which maps to fields on the object. Admin can enter rich text with all available formatting easily.

Comment: Glad I helped :)